# Order By on date field starting in a middle point of the dates range

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table "A" with a "date" field. I want to make a select query and order the rows with previous dates in a descending order, and then, the rows with next dates in ascending order, all in the same query. Is it possible?

For example, table "A":

```
id    date
---------------------
a     march-20
b     march-21
c     march-22
d     march-23
e     march-24
```

I'd like to get, having as a starting date "march-22", this result:

```
id    date
---------------------
c     march-22
b     march-21
a     march-20
d     march-23
e     march-24
```

In one query, because I'm doing it with two of them and it's slow, because the only difference is the sorting, and the joins I have to do are a bit "heavy".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post the queries you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this -

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY IF(
    date <= '2012-03-22', 
    DATEDIFF('2000-01-01', date),
    DATEDIFF(date, '2000-01-01') 
);
```

Here is a link to a test on SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31a3f/13

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong, sorry :(
From documentation:

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final UNION result. If ORDER BY appears without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway.

This should do the trick. I'm not 100% sure about adding an order in a UNION...

```
SELECT * FROM A where date <= now() ORDER BY date DESC
UNION SELECT * FROM A where date > now() ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the real question here is how to do the joining once. Create a temporary table with the result of joining, and make the 2 selects from that table. So it will be be time consuming only on creation (once) not on select query (twice).

```
CREATE TABLE tmp SELECT ... JOIN -- do the heavy duty here
```

With this you can make the two select statenets as you originally did.